# How to get selected/removed value in <v-select> multiple vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-select

I have this v-select :

```
<v-select
    multiple
    v-model="group.structures"
    :options="filter"
    label="name"
    @input="changed"
></v-select>
```

When I get the attribute of my function "changed", I got an array with all selected values when I add or remove an item from my v-select.

```
changed(value) {
    console.log(value); // Return an array with all items in (group.structures).
}
```

I don't want to get all the array but only the selected/removed value. Is there any way to get the selected value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to achieve what you want is store the previous value in variable  then compare the new value with it

```js
data() {
  return {
    previousSelectedStructures: [];
    // ...
  }
}
```

```js
changed(value) {
    let added = value.filter(
      (val) => !this.previousSelectedStructures.includes(val)
    );
    let removed = this.previousSelectedStructures.filter(
      (val) => !value.includes(val)
    );

    // Do some stuff

    console.log(value);
    this.previousSelectedStructures = value;
}
```

Comment: This gives me undefind includes.. any help in that?

Answer (score 0):

Wow! It works! Thank you!

For those who have the same request, don't forget to fill your previousSelectedStructures up with the existing content :

```
created(){
        this.previousSelectedStructures = this.group.structures;
    },
```